# How to manipulate data in a Solidity smart contract?

Tags: transactions, contract-development, gas, web3js

I have a smart contract with some members which should get modified on certain events. For simplicity, let's imagine we have a greeter contract.

If I call `greeter.greet()` in the JavaScript console, it responds with something like `Hello World`. But what if I want to count the number of greetings and store them inside the contract?

My first try was the following:

```
contract greeter
{
  string greeting;
  uint calls;

  function greeter ( string _greeting ) public
  {
    greeting = _greeting;
    calls = 0;
  }

  function greet ( ) constant returns ( string )
  {
    calls = calls + 1; // does not work
    return greeting;
  }
}
```

The calls variable was not updated. My first guess is that I need to somehow create a transaction to pay for the gas. I used `web3.js` to deploy the contract. Should I use web3 also for calling `greet()` with a transaction?

Or could I fund the contract account with some Ether to enable the contract to pay its own gas? How to manipulate data in a Solidity smart contract?

Comment: I have not looked at web3.js yet but I am curious to learn how you, as you wrote, deployed your contract with it. Could you please point me at further details?

Comment: @hcvst you can follow my baby steps deploying with web3js on [github](https://github.com/5chdn/greeter-erica/blob/master/erica.html#L20).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because your `greet()` function is marked `constant`, web3 by default simulates the call and returns the value, but no transaction is sent, and thus no state changes are retained. This behavior can be forced in non-constant methods using `contract.method.call()`.

To call the function in a way that does send a transaction and update the chain, use `greeter.greet.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, gas:100000})`.

Unfortunately, while other contracts will recieve the proper return value, web3 will return a transaction hash, as opposed to a return value. In this case, it makes sense to use [Events](http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contracts.htmlhttp://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contracts.html?highlight=events#events).

For example, the solidity would look something like:

```
contract greeter { 
    string greeting; 
    uint calls; 
    event Greet (string greeting);
    function greeter ( string _greeting ) public { 
        greeting = _greeting; 
        calls = 0; 
     }
     function greet ( ) public returns ( string ) { 
         calls = calls + 1; 
         Greet(greeting);
          return greeting; 
     } 
 }
```

And to get a return value:

```
 greeter.greet.sendTransaction(
    {from:eth.coinbase, gas:100000},

    function (error, result){ 
    var event = greeter.Greet()
    event.watch(
        function(error, result){ 
             if (!error) console.log(result.args.greeting); 
         }
    );
)
```

Comment: Upvoted, good point about the return value; edited my answer to refer to yours for web3js and events, and briefly mentioned the contract-to-contract case.

Comment: I think you want to remove the "constant" in greet()?  Also, "result.greeting" might not be precise.  IIRC may need something like "result.args.greeting".

Comment: @eth Thanks, I totally forgot about the constant, and the `result.args.greeting` is correct.

Answer (score 7):

The **problem is that `greet` is a `constant` function** so no state changes are allowed.  Changing the value of something in storage, would be a state change.

**Solution: remove `constant`.**

Yes, you should use web3 [`sendTransaction`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) when you want a state change.  `sendTransaction` is the [default](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#example-48) for non-constant functions, but it wasn't used because `constant` was specified.  Note that the return value will [only be accessible from another contract](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#get-return-value-from-non-constant-function-from-another-contract) -- with web3js transactions, Events will need to be used to get the return value as [Tjaden Hess answered](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/744/42).

More from the [FAQ](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-marked-constant-and-one-that-is-not):

> *What is the difference between a function marked constant and one that is not?*
>
> `constant` functions can perform some action and return a value, but
>   cannot change state (this is not yet enforced by the compiler). In
>   other words, a constant function cannot save or update any variables
>   within the contract or wider blockchain. These functions are called
>   using `c.someFunction(...)` from geth or any other web3.js environment.
>
> “non-constant” functions (those lacking the constant specifier) must
>   be called with `c.someMethod.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[x],
>   gas: 1000000});` That is, because they can change state, they have to
>   have a gas payment sent along to get the work done.

---

To answer the remaining question, [a contract cannot pay for its own gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/144/42), in the way that might be imagined with this example, so funding it with Ether doesn't help.