# Returning dynamic arrays: out of gas

Tags: arrays, out-of-gas, truffle-test

I'm trying to return a dynamic array of structures from a Solidity function to a client. Since I need to build the result, I'm declaring a storage variable and add elements to it:

```
function conversations(address user) public view returns (Conversation[]){
    Conversation[] userConversations;
    userConversations.push(conversations[0]);
    return userConversations;
}
```

However, I keep getting an `out of gas` exception in my Truffle tests. How can it run out of gas when it's a view function? I understand that `userConversations` is a storage variable (or I won't be able to execute `push` on it), but does it really modify the state of the contract? If it does, how do you rewrite it so that you can get a dynamic array?

Comment: I've asked a similar question before but I've no definitive answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28040/can-i-eth-call-a-non-constant-function-from-javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> userConversations.push(conversations[0]);

definitely modifies the state, so this cannot be used in a `view` function.
You basically need to write a getter function to this setter function or make `userConversations` public, in that case it will get a getter function  automatically.

Comment: userConversations is a temp variable created just to build up an array to return.

Also, a getter for an array cannot return this array -- it's a function that requires an index and returns an element of this array. Am I right?

Comment: When I try to return a field which is a dynamic array, it says ` Error: invalid solidity type!: tuple[]`

Comment: You can't return struct as of now, it's available only in experimental version. I'm wondering why compiler won't throw error.  
Edit: also i think `userConversations` actually is being written to storage, as it doesn't have `memory` keyword.

Comment: Other than that, it's of course not possible yet to return dynamically sized data yet.

Answer (score 4):

You get an out of gas because your `Conversation[] userConversations;` that you believe is in memory is actually on storage.

Try to change it to `Conversation[] memory userConversations;` and you will see that it no longer compiles because `.push` is not available on memory arrays.

How about you try that:

```
function getConversations() public view returns (Conversation [] userConversations) {
    uint length = conversations.length;
    userConversations = new Conversation[](length);
    for (uint i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        userConversations[i] = conversations[i];
    }
}
```