# Using 'call' from a constant function

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, evm, assembly

I am trying to determine the behavior of `call` when executed from a constant function.

Of course, the compiler issues a warning on that:

> Warning: Function declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state and thus requires non-payable (the default) or payable

But since this is not an error, I can move forward and see what happens.

Please note that I'm on Solc 0.4.25; I'm pretty sure that things have changed on Solc v0.5.x.

Anyway, I went ahead and implemented a pair of small contracts in order to test this:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Callee {
    uint256 public xxxx;

    function func() external returns (uint256) {
        xxxx = 123;
        return 456;
    }
}

contract Caller {
    Callee private callee = new Callee();
    uint256 public yyyy;

    function callFromConstantFunc() external view returns (uint256) {
        uint256[1] memory retv;
        address dest = address(callee);
        bytes memory selector = abi.encodeWithSelector(callee.func.selector);
        assembly {
            let status := call(gas, dest, 0, add(selector, 32), mload(selector), retv, 32)
            if iszero(status) {
                revert(0, 0)
            }
        }
        return retv[0];
    }

    function callFromNonConstantFunc() external returns (uint256) {
        uint256[1] memory retv;
        address dest = address(callee);
        bytes memory selector = abi.encodeWithSelector(callee.func.selector);
        assembly {
            let status := call(gas, dest, 0, add(selector, 32), mload(selector), retv, 32)
            if iszero(status) {
                revert(0, 0)
            }
        }
        yyyy = retv[0];
    }

    function xxxx() external view returns (uint256) {
        return callee.xxxx();
    }
}
```

Then I tested both methods via Truffle:

```
contract("Test", function(accounts) {
    it("callFromConstantFunc", async function() {
        const caller = await artifacts.require("Caller").new();
        const retv = await caller.callFromConstantFunc();
        const xxxx = await caller.xxxx();
        console.log(`retv = ${retv}, xxxx = ${xxxx}`);
    });
    it("callFromNonConstantFunc", async function() {
        const caller = await artifacts.require("Caller").new();
        await caller.callFromNonConstantFunc();
        const retv = await caller.yyyy();
        const xxxx = await caller.xxxx();
        console.log(`retv = ${retv}, xxxx = ${xxxx}`);
    });
});
```

The results are rather staggering IMO:

```
callFromConstantFunc: retv = 456, xxxx = 0
callFromNonConstantFunc: retv = 456, xxxx = 123
```

As you can see, when I invoked `Callee.func` from `Caller.callFromConstantFunc`, the transaction has completed without reverting, but the value of `Callee.xxxx` has remained unchanged.

For the record, I have also invoked `Callee.func` from `Caller.callFromNonConstantFunc`, where the value of `Callee.xxxx` has changed as expected.

Of course, changing `call` to `staticcall` would cause both `Caller` functions to revert, because the `Callee` function itself is not constant.

However, my question focuses on the behavior of `call`, and I'm trying to figure out how it is possible for a transaction to complete successfully and yet - without "doing the job".

Some clarification on the parameters that I pass to `call`:

- `gas` - the remaining amount of gas for the transaction
- `dest` - the address of the `Callee` instance
- `0` - the amount of wei passed to the function
- `add(selector, 32)` - the start address of the input (see explanation below)
- `mload(selector)` - the length of the input (see explanation below)
- `retv` - the start address of the output
- `32` - the length of the output

Because `selector` is a `bytes` array, the first 32 bytes contain the length of this array, and the actual data starts immediately after.

I have executed the test via Ganache.

Can someone please confirm that this is the expected behavior if I deploy such contract to a "real" network? Also, how is it even possible for this kind of behavior to be "allowed" on Ethereum?

Thank you.

Comment: The call to `callFromConstantFunc` doesn't create a transaction, so there's no way for it to modify the internal state of the contract. Calling a non constant function outside a contract is useful if you want to simulate behavior without spending ether. I've previously asked a similar question that remains unanswered https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28040/can-i-eth-call-a-non-constant-function-from-javascript

Comment: @Ismael: Thank you. I'd expect a revert in this case, but the function call completes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/contracts.html#view-functions):

> The compiler does not enforce yet that a view method is not modifying state. It raises a warning though.

Declaring a method as `view` will indicate in the ABI that the method is intended to be accessed via a call rather than a transaction, but this behavior is in no way enforced. `eth_call` executes a transaction locally without broadcasting it and so without actually modifying the state. As @Ismael mentioned in the comments, this is useful for simulating a transaction to ensure it will not revert without actually spending any ether.

For your example, if you execute `Caller.callFromConstantFunc()` as a transaction rather than a call it will modify the state of `xxxx` in `Callee`:

```
>>> caller = accounts[0].deploy(Caller)
Transaction sent: 0xa63c8d2e484c64b92e3a99e67ba2edf0fa7026a6b7b7d753c7c4e0956edf7831
Caller.constructor confirmed - block: 1   gas used: 367205 (5.48%)
Caller deployed at: 0x5f7Cc61aDD8Cf64583f14993529AFe393d0BD9A8

>>> caller.callFromConstantFunc()  # executes as a call, state will not change
456
>>> caller.xxxx()
0

>>> tx = caller.callFromConstantFunc.transact({'from': accounts[0]})
Transaction sent: 0xf8c1b8e22650f90ed929f2b55aad2c50c878c9fb48d58d3587baf9b2f1d8bc03
Caller.callFromConstantFunc confirmed - block: 2   gas used: 42886 (0.64%)
>>> tx.return_value
456
>>> caller.xxxx()
123
```

When writing a contract that does modify state in a view function, you must always consider that someone *can* call it as a transaction and so any change it makes *can* be permanent.