# Truffle: 'func.call()' retrieves the return-value of a non-constant function

Tags: web3js, truffle, contract-invocation, events

I've just learned that one can easily obtain the return-value of a non-constant function, by using `myContract.func.call()` (instead of `myContract.func()`, which retrieves a response object).

Up until now, I've always added inside `func` an event containing the return-value, and then parsed the response object returned from `myContract.func()` in order to extract that value.

**This has also been the guidance in dozens of answers across his website!**

Questions:

1. How is it possible that so many people here have missed this?
2. Is it possibly just a tweak added in Truffle, or can one rely on it when writing an operational Web3.js script?

For the record, I am using Truffle v4.1.14, which relies on Web3 v0.20.6.

Here is the contract that I've used for testing this:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract MyContract {
    uint public kkk;
    function func() public returns (uint) {
        kkk += 100;
        return kkk;
    }
}
```

And here is the actual test:

```
contract("Test", function(accounts) {
    it("MyContract", async function() {
        const myContract = await artifacts.require("MyContract").new();
        const x = await myContract.func();
        const y = await myContract.func.call();
        console.log(x);
        console.log(y.toFixed());
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: When called as `.call()` it shouldn't create a transaction, any change should not be persistent. Are you testing with ganache or geth/parity?

Comment: @Ismael: Ganache. Are you saying that I should have called `kkk()` after everything and check its value?

Comment: Yes, ´myContract.func.call()´ does not modify contracts storage. I asked a related question previously that is not answered yet https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28040/can-i-eth-call-a-non-constant-function-from-javascript.

Comment: @Ismael: So it is in fact not the correct way of executing non-constant functions in your tests (unless, perhaps, you're interested in a unit-test for that specific function). And it is most certainly not the correct way of executing non-constant functions in your operational scripts (my 2nd question). Am I right? That would also mean that at least part of the answer below is wrong.

Comment: Yes, he is mixing web3 v0.20 syntax with v1.2 documentation. Also Truffle v4 has a different syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I always use `myContract.func.call()`. Actuall I have never heard that `myContract.func()`.

After all this is the recommended way of doing it!! Furthermore, the performance is better (I think).

1. Maybe that's your perception? Read the official web3 documentation. I read every page of it. Here is the [link to the correct article](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call).
2. I don't use truffle and it works nonetheless. This function is implemented in plain web3.

I hope this information helps.

Comment: You are mixing syntax of web3 v0.20 with v1.2 documentation. Also the question was about Truffle v4 that has different syntax than web3 v1.2 and closer to web3 v0.20.