# Retrieve the return value from a non-constant function

Tags: solidity

Recently, I was reading a paper in which the writers stated that

> *"In the Ethereum smart contract, the return value of the nonconstant function can only be obtained through logs event."*

However, I think that you can retrieve a value from a non-constant function by using `myContract.func.call()`.
What is your opinion? Thanks!

(Btw, a similar question has been asked here; [Truffle: 'func.call()' retrieves the return-value of a non-constant function](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74252/truffle-func-call-retrieves-the-return-value-of-a-non-constant-function) but it is not answered).

Comment: Can you link the paper?

Answer (score 0):

`myContract.getValue.call()` - *constant* function => *read* current state (does not create any transaction).

`myContract.setValue.send()` - *non-constant* function => *write* (create transaction) and must be mined. Because of this, you cannot obtain the result **immediately**. A workaround for this is to just emit the *event*.