# Where to check value returnd by function in wallet?

Tags: contract-development, wallets

where do I check the value returned by a function in 
Ethereum wallet (I'm using v. 0.8.3)?

I have set a test net and it works fine. 
So, after I call a function of my deployed contract , I mine on it and the transaction is executed. I see fron an event that the value returned s correct.

ex.:

```
 function getMyvalue()  returns (uint256 valueInWeis)  {

    print(value); // event is printed correctly

    return value;

}
```

Here is a screenshot[image: with my transaction related to a function called after exectution]

Where can I see the value returned (without having to check the events) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function modifies contract state, then it always returns transaction hash. There is no alternative to get return value other than using `events`. See [How to get values returned by non constant transaction functions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/how-to-get-values-returned-by-non-constant-transaction-functions)

However if your function doesn't modify the contract state(as in your case), you should probably use `constant` functions.

```
function getMyvalue() constant returns (uint256 valueInWeis)  {

    print(value); // event is printed correctly

    return value;

}
```

> [What is the difference between a function marked constant and one that
>   is not?](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-marked-constant-and-one-that-is-not)
>
> constant functions can perform some action and return a value, but
>   cannot change state (this is not yet enforced by the compiler). In
>   other words, a constant function cannot save or update any variables
>   within the contract or wider blockchain. These functions are called
>   using c.someFunction(...) from geth or any other web3.js environment.
>
> “non-constant” functions (those lacking the constant specifier) must
>   be called with c.someMethod.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[x],
>   gas: 1000000}); That is, because they can change state, they have to
>   have a gas payment sent along to get the work done.