# Retrieve data from smart contract using sendTransaction

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, web3js, mining

Lets take a very basic smart contract that has one function in which you send a number and it will return the square. It has another function that returns a fixed string.

```
contract MyContract {
  uint public version;
  address public previousPublishedVersion;

  function ping() returns (string param){
    param = "pong";
  }

  function squareNumber(uint num) returns (uint256 numSqr) {
    numSqr = (num * num);
  }
}
```

Now to deploy the contract I use

```
myContract.new({
  data: MyContract.compiled_code,
  gas: gasNeeded * ethConfig.gas_factor,
  from: ethConfig.primary_address
}, (err, myContract) => {
    if(!err) {
     if(!myContract.address) {
         console.log('contract trasnaction hash ' + myContract.transactionHash)
     } else {
        console.log('contract address ' + myContract.address)
        resolve({
         primary_address: ethConfig.primary_address,
         contract_address: myContract.address,
         gas_estimate: gasNeeded
        })
     }
  } else {
    reject(err)
  }
});
```

This fires two callbacks, one with the transaction hash and one with the address once its mined. However this method is not there for `sendTransaction`. I have read that using `getTransactionReceipt` or checking block numbers is a good way to check whether the transaction has been mined or not.

```
  myContract.ping.call(null, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    } else {
      resolve({
        primary_address: ethConfig.primary_address,
        returnValue: data
      })
    }
  })
```

But for squaring the number I use

```
  myContract.squareNumber.estimateGas(10, (err, gasNeeded) => {
    if (err) reject(err)
    myContract.squareNumber.sendTransaction(
      10,
      {
        gas: gasNeeded * config.ethConfig.gas_factor,
        from: config.ethConfig.primary_address
      }, (err, data) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      resolve({
        primary_address: config.ethConfig.primary_address,
        numSquare : data
      })
    })
  })
```

Now for a `call` function, I can get the data directly without any mining to be done, however the [docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransaction) say that the value returned from sendTransaction() is the hash of it, and then we are to use `getTransactionReceipt()` to actually confirm when the block was mined.

My question is simply this, how exactly do I structure my `web3js` code, to get the value returned (10*10) from the solidity function `squareNumber()`.

I have wrapped all APIs shown above in promises but just skipped that part as its long and not related to web3js in any way.

Answer (score 2):

After adding an event like `SquareComputed` (see
[How to get values returned by non constant transaction functions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/how-to-get-values-returned-by-non-constant-transaction-functions)) and web3.js [Contract Events](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events) example

> ```
> var event = myContractInstance.MyEvent({valueA: 23} [, additionalFilterObject])
>
> // watch for changes
> event.watch(function(error, result){
>   if (!error)
>     console.log(result);
> });
> ```

this would lead to code like:

```
var event = myContractInstance.SquareComputed({});

// watch for changes
event.watch(function(error, result){
  if (!error)
    resolve({
        primary_address: config.ethConfig.primary_address,
        numSquare : result  // need to access the properties of result to obtain the actual square 
    })
  event.stopWatching();
});
```

Do the above *before* `myContractInstance.squareNumber.sendTransaction`.
The `resolve({numSquare:...})` in the original code should be moved to inside the `watch` as above.

Other web3.js APIs such as `web3.eth.filter` can also be used (see
[How do I retrieve the Voted events from The DAO](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4452/how-do-i-retrieve-the-voted-events-from-the-dao)).

This questions asks "how exactly do I structure my web3js code, to get the value returned (10*10) from the solidity function squareNumber()", otherwise for an overview see [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call).

Comment: Understood what you wrote and the links, however if I have multi instances of this contract created on the blockchain, say each person has his own unique contract instance deployed, then using `event.watch` will become problematic cause it will pick up any event logs fired.

Comment: If each user has their own contract and own UI, above could work.  If each user has multiple contracts, maybe an array could be used like: `event[i] = myContractInstance[i].SquareComputed({})`.  Another possibility is to have an indexed parameter to the event like userId, and filter on it like `event = myContractInstance.MyEvent({userId: 23}` (May need to ask separate question if we get too abstract and need to be specific.)

Answer (score 0):

With Web3.js v1.0.0 you can get the event fired by your SquareComputed transation (`sendTransation()` equivalent method is now `send()`), see `send() return` in [the documentation](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id22)