# How are returns objects converted in geth?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I have a function which returns an uint, but actually gets an object - how is that converted.

e.g.

> f

```
   "0x91f35a1267f2c8d763f7a3fb35ffac845fcbb1417a64b030ed79cbaa4e29694f"
```

`f` is defined as the return to the following function:

```
function testReturn() returns (uint) {
    studentAge=90;
    return 89;
 }
```

There must be a way to convert the return from this function.

The contract is defined as:

```
contract CollegeAdmin {
    uint8 public studentAge=21;
    uint16 public studentIncome=15000;
    uint8 public studentScore=4;

    uint8 public studentAttendance=96;

    function testReturn() returns (uint) {
        studentAge=90;
        return 89;
    }
}
```

Hence `f` is defined using:

```
f = con.testReturn()
```

Also, `con` is defined:

```
con = eth.contract(abi).at(addr)
```

abi - abi for contract
addr - contract address

Answer (score 1):

I tested by adding constant and that worked. I am unsure what it returned before, but with constant added it worked -

```
   function testReturn() constant returns (uint) {
       studentAge=90;
       return 89;
   }
```

Comment: Constants methods can not modify state. SO the studentAge will not be updated to 90.

Comment: That is useful to know about the state variable. I am only testing what functions can do. Constant is needed to return the integer apparently.

Comment: Yes. In case you have to modify state as well as return values. You have to Solidity events. :)

Comment: The issue is all about constant. It seems that is needed to do a call otherwise sendTransaction applies.

Answer (score 0):

> Non-contract functions can not return values. Use Events instead.

Or mark your function **constant** (or **view**) (if the function doesn't modify the state).

```
function testReturn() constant returns (uint) {
    studentAge=90;
    return 89;
 }
```

The following statements are considered modifying the state:

- Writing to state variables.
- Emitting events.
- Creating other contracts.
- Using selfdestruct.
- Sending Ether via calls.
- Calling any function not marked view or pure.
- Using low-level calls.
- Using inline assembly that contains certain opcodes.

> If you are not reading any state variables better make function
>   **pure**.

```
function testReturn() pure returns (uint) {
        return 89;
     }
```

Read more about [view functions](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#view-functions) and [pure functions](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#pure-functions).

Comment: The func is coded in a smart contract, and deployed into the ethereum blockchain and then referred via geth and the con object, the question I asked related to converting the returned object into a number. It is not related to view and pure, or events.

Comment: The smart-contract function can not return a value if this is not constant. It only returns transaction hash. The return type can use while while making calls from some other function.

Comment: Better if you post the code you are using along with the object you are getting.

Comment: I am only asking how to convert objects in geth.

Comment: What object did you want to convert? You are calling a non-constant function and this will not return you 89 (as you may be expecting). You need to use Events. See: [returning value from non-constant functions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/how-to-get-values-returned-by-non-constant-transaction-functions)

Comment: My issue is not related to events in anyway. I am only asking how to see a number using the geth console returned from a function. If my func did not return 89 what did it return?

Comment: It will return the transaction hash. You call a non-constant function that is changing state variable (studentAge). So this transaction is broadcasted to the network and when this tx is mined, the value of state variable will be updated.