# Getting hex instead of uint through mapping

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

I have a simple method where I count how many times certain address has called method of smart contract. Here is code:

```
mapping (address => uint) countTotal;

function countSends() public returns(uint retClicks) {
    clicksTotal[msg.sender]++;
    return countTotal[msg.sender];
}
```

Obviously I expect that on first send I'll get 1, then 2, then 3...

But for some reason what I get back through `web3js` is hexadecimal value like `0xea6166fd3f8249c3dd3ed1dcbb3af9989aebdcf9f5eb079fc6d570296e6f4509`. How can I get regular unsigned integer?

EDIT: Duplicate nannies linked to theoretical discussion... this much better explains what you need to do: [How to get values returned by non constant transaction functions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/how-to-get-values-returned-by-non-constant-transaction-functions)

Comment: Please share your code. But my guess: that's a transaction hash. Transactions don't really have return values... if you want to mutate state and "return" a value, you're probably going to end up using an event or a `call` after the transaction.

Comment: @smarx Yeah, just looking into it... seems that I need to wait for transaction to be confirmed in order for correct count to be returned.

Comment: Well, you need to wait for the transaction to be mined before the change has taken place, but there still won't be a return value.

Comment: Simple example of using an event to get the return value: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/how-to-get-values-returned-by-non-constant-transaction-functions

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you got a typographic error. Instead of **clicksTotal**[msg.sender]++; change it to **countTotal**[msg.sender]++;

Try this.

> ```
> mapping (address => uint) countTotal;
>
> function countSends() public returns(uint retClicks) {
>     countTotal[msg.sender]++;
>     return countTotal[msg.sender];
> }
> ```