# A proxy factory does not return the clone contract address

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, proxy-contracts

I have three smart contracts:

An abstract one:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";

/**
 * @title Base contract for state machines
 */
abstract contract StateMachine is AccessControl {
  event Transition(address sender, bytes32 fromState, bytes32 toState);

  struct State {
    // a boolean to check if the state is actually created
    bool hasBeenCreated;
    // a mapping of functions that can be executed when in this state
    mapping(bytes4 => bool) allowedFunctions;
    // a list of all the roles that have been configured for this state
    bytes32[] allowedRoles;
    // a list of all the preconditions that have been configured for this state
    function(bytes32, bytes32) internal view[] preConditions;
    // a list of callbacks to execute before the state transition completes
    function(bytes32, bytes32) internal[] callbacks;
    // a list of states that can be transitioned to
    bytes32[] nextStates;
    // function that executes logic and then does a StateTransition
    bytes4 preFunction;
  }

  struct StateTransition {
    bytes32 fromState;
    bytes32 toState;
    address actor;
    uint256 timestamp;
  }
  

  StateTransition[] public history;

  mapping(bytes32 => State) internal states;
  bytes32[] internal possibleStates;
  bytes32 internal currentState;

  // a list of selectors that might be allowed functions
  bytes4[] internal knownSelectors;
  mapping(bytes4 => bool) internal knownSelector;

  // a list of allowed functions per state
  bytes4[] internal stateFunctions;
  mapping(bytes32 => bytes4[]) internal stateFunction;

  // To Check if there is a relation between one state and another
  mapping(bytes32 => mapping(bytes32 => bool)) internal nextStateToState;
  
  
  /**
   * @dev Abstract function to setup the state machine configuration
   */
  function setupStateMachine(address Admin) internal virtual {}

  function createState(bytes32 stateName) internal {
    require(!states[stateName].hasBeenCreated, "this state has already been created");
    states[stateName].hasBeenCreated = true;
    possibleStates.push(stateName);
  }


  /**
   * @notice Configures the initial state of an object
   */
  function setInitialState(bytes32 initialState) internal {
    require(states[initialState].hasBeenCreated, "the initial state has not been created yet");
    require(
      currentState == 0,
      "the current state has already been set, so you cannot configure the initial state and override it"
    );
    currentState = initialState;
  }
}
```

My implementation (from which I want to create clones):

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import "./StateMachine.sol";


contract SupplyChain is StateMachine, Initializable {
  bytes32 public constant STATE_DEMAND_GENERATED = 'DEMAND GENERATED';

  bytes32 public constant ROLE_ADMIN = 'ROLE_ADMIN';

  bytes32[] public _roles = [ROLE_ADMIN];

  
  function initialize() public virtual initializer {
    address Admin = msg.sender;
    _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, Admin);
    _setRoleAdmin(ROLE_ADMIN, DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE);
    setupStateMachine(Admin);
    }


  function setupStateMachine(address Admin) internal override {
    //create all states

    createState(STATE_DEMAND_GENERATED);
    // add properties

    setInitialState(STATE_DEMAND_GENERATED);
  }
}
```

And then my proxy factory:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.6;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/Clones.sol";
import "./SupplyChain.sol";

contract SupplyChainFactory {
    
    address immutable proxyImplementation;
    
    constructor() public {
        proxyImplementation = address(new SupplyChain());
    }
    
    function createSupplyChain() external returns (address) {
        address clone = Clones.clone(proxyImplementation);
        SupplyChain(clone).initialize();
        return clone;
    }
}
```

I am currently only testing in Remix but right now when I click createSupplyChain(), it returns :
`[vm] from: 0x5B3...eddC4 to: SupplyChain.(fallback) 0x1d1...3B8BD value: 0 wei data: 0x4a4...5a1b3 logs: 22 hash: 0xde0...0f27f`

but in the decoded output I have nothing, can you guys explain me what I do wrong? or what I don't understand here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Transactions do not return a value, to get a value from a transaction you can emit an event with the value as parameter, see here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/how-to-get-values-returned-by-non-constant-transaction-functions.