# NFT implementation of OpenZeppelin ERC721 ownerOf always returns "ERC721: owner query for nonexistent token"

Tags: solidity, truffle, erc-721

I am trying to implement ERC721 standard of OpenZeppelin. However, when I try to verify the owner of the token in tests I always get "ERC721: owner query for nonexistent token". Other methods, such as balanceOf, work perfectly. Here are the implementations:

**ERC721.sol (implements IERC721.sol)**

```
 /**
 * @dev See {IERC721-ownerOf}.
 */
function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (address) {
    address owner = _owners[tokenId];
    require(owner != address(0), "ERC721: owner query for nonexistent token");
    return owner;
}
```

**My NFT token NFTToken.sol**

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "./ERC721.sol";

contract NFTToken is ERC721 {

uint256 public tokenCounter;
address private owner;

constructor() ERC721 ("NFTToken", "NFTK") {
    tokenCounter = 0;
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function createCollectible() public returns (uint256){
    uint256 tokenID = tokenCounter;
    _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenID);
    tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
    return tokenID;
}
}
```

**NfttokenTest.js**

```
it("should verify that the account[0] is owner of the token 0", async function(){
    const instance = await NFTToken.deployed();
    const tx = await instance.createCollectible();
    const tokenId = await instance.createCollectible.call();
    const owner = await instance.ownerOf(tokenId);
    assert.equal(owner, accounts[0], "Owner not correct");
});
```

Why does this call to **ownerOf** fails here?

Comment: See this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/122338/, don't use `.call()` if you want to persist changes in the contract. If you want to get the return value use events.

Comment: Thanks for advice but I have used the line before to persist state (without `.call()`) and I still don't know why the call to check the owner fails

Comment: It shouldn't fail with a valid tokenId. Did you check the tokenId is valid?

Comment: Finally found the mistake - I was calling createCollectible() multiple times which increased the counter and always returned a higher tokenId. So yes, the tokenId was the main problem. Thanks for your help!