# How to get address of new contract? (hardhat)

Tags: addresses, hardhat-deploy

Lets say i have a contract which includes a function that deploys new ERC721 contract:

```
function createCollection(
    uint256 _price, uint256 _maxSupply, string memory _name, string memory _symbol, 
    address _requsetFrom, string memory _uri, bytes32 salt
    ) external payable returns(address)  {
        if (msg.value < s_createFee) {
            revert CollectionCreator__InsufficientAmount();
        }
        CollectionV2 newNft = new CollectionV2(_name,_symbol,_price,_maxSupply,_requsetFrom, _uri);
        address _contractAddress = address(newNft);
        ownerToCollection[_requsetFrom].push(_contractAddress);
    emit NewCollection(_requsetFrom, _contractAddress);
    return(_contractAddress);
}
```

And i returned the address of new contract, but when i want to get address of new contract in the backend it returns me the transaction:

```
const Collection = await ERC721Creator.createCollection(10,100,'test','tst',deployer.address,'someuri')
  await Collection.wait(1)
  console.log(Collection);
```

It returns me a ton of information about this transaction, what i must to do?
thanks

---

According to Rohan answer i got address this way:

```
const Collection = await ERC721Creator.createCollection(10,100,'test','tst',deployer.address,'someuri')
  const tx = await Collection.wait(1)
  const newContractAddress = tx.events[0].args[1]
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/how-to-get-values-returned-by-non-constant-transaction-functions; you need to get the data from the NewCollection event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get values returned by non constant transaction functions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/how-to-get-values-returned-by-non-constant-transaction-functions)

Comment: It says that i should use events to get the address, as you can see i defined event but for another usage , i'm looking for a way  to do it easier ,if it's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is assign your `await Collection.wait(1)` to a variable such as

`const txReceipt = await Collection.wait(1)`

Then you can console.log your address like this

`console.log("Your new address:", txReceipt.events[0].args._contractAddress)`

you may need to use a different `events` index depending on if you make any contract function calls that emit events inside them