# Is there any case where a contract will use gas?

Tags: solidity, ether, gas

I was wondering, why and when is it important to fund your contract with ether?
Is this really only ever if you want to send ether from your contract?

Does a contract ever need to pay gas for something rather than the caller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO, till yet, contract cannot pay the gas for the execution of a transaction. If the function of a contract, in turn, call the function of another contract, gas will be provided by the user calling the function of first contract.

This can add a bit more : [Can contracts pay the gas instead of the message sender?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144/can-contracts-pay-the-gas-instead-of-the-message-sender)