# Gas deduction on contract creation inside a contract

Tags: contract-development, gas

I want to create a Contract (TokenTimelock from Open Zeppelin) inside of a registry contract.
It seems as if my contract needs gas to do this.
So I am wondering about using delegate call because I want the caller to pay for the gas, or I need to store ETH in my resgistry contract which I do not really want to do.

Am I correct that if a Contract is creating another contract that it is the one that will need to pay gas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, a contract cannot pay the gas for a transaction. In any form, it will be always an external account who will be paying it. Ether stored in a contract can be sent to another ethereum address but cannot be used as a fuel(gas) to a transaction.

See this:

- [Is there any case where a contract will use gas?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8585/is-there-any-case-where-a-contract-will-use-gas?rq=1)
- [Can contracts pay the gas instead of the message sender?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144/can-contracts-pay-the-gas-instead-of-the-message-sender)

Comment: Thanks, I need to figure out why my contract reverts if I create a new contract inside a function and add to a mapping (in the same mapping)

Comment: Sure, you can ask a new question if you got stuck somewhere.