# Trying to send 295 NGC from my ether wallet to hitbit and getting the following error message

Tags: altcoin

Insufficient funds. The account you tried to send transaction from does not have enough funds. Required 467680000000000 and got: 0.

Comment: Do you have enough ether in the wallet to pay for the gas fee?

Comment: the 295 ngc is all i have in the wallet i knoiw there is a gas fee but im struggling to calculate it and when i try to send a smaller amount of ngc it still wont work

Comment: The gas fee is paid in ether, so you need to have the ether in your wallet to move the ngc from your wallet. The amount of tokens you send doesn't factor into the price of moving them.

Comment: is there no way of getting my ngc out without buying ether?

Comment: I can send you a few $ of eth for the gas fee if you're comfortable sending me your address, you can private message it to me on reddit - my username there is the same as here, flygoing

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21001/do-users-of-erc20-coins-need-to-hold-ether?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

A token transfer on the Ethereum network actually invokes a method on a smart contract. All smart contract calls require "gas", [paid for in Ether](https://ethgasstation.info/). This is why [you can't move any tokens without also having Ether](https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/gas/error-insufficient-funds-message.html).

Comment: ok thanks any idea how much ether i will need to purchase to move this amount

Comment: At that gas price, you'd need `0.00046768` Ether (about 0.50 USD as of now). You can adjust your gas price using the dropdown at the top of the page; I generally recommend using [the "SafeLow" value published by the eth gas station](https://ethgasstation.info/). Also, you might want to wait a day or so; ETH prices are fluctuating a lot right now causing extra load on the network (which means higher gas prices).