# Who decides what kind of token reward a miner gets for mining a block?

Tags: erc-20, mining

**Preamble:**

- To my understanding, a Bitcoin miner creates a new block, put
  some necessary information in it incl. some transactions from other
  participants and one transaction which sends 25 Bitcoin to his
  own address as 'Reward' in case he manage to actually 'mine' the
  block by solving a cryptologic riddle.

**My Question:**

- How does it behave on ethereum?

  On the ethereum blockchain new blocks will be also mined. But who
  decides which reward the miner gets in case he successfully manage to
  solve the riddle? Is it like on BTC that the miner itself just adds (one)
  transaction with a specific amount of a specific Token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... which sends 25 Bitcoin to his own address as 'Reward'...

The reward hasn't been 25 BTC since July 2017, when it halved to 12.5.

> But who decides which reward the miner gets in case he successfully manage to solve the riddle?

The title of your question implies that by "which reward" you mean the *type* of reward, rather than quantity. Standard block rewards are in ETH, not ERC-20 (or any other) tokens.

The current standard block reward is 3 ETH, which will reduce to 2 ETH on the 16th January 2019, as part of the Constantinople hard fork. See [EIP-1234](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1234.md).

---

However, it's worth considering transaction fees - which are also paid to the miner - as well as the main block reward.

It's possible at some point that transaction fees will be able to be paid in tokens. See the following:

- [ERC865: Pay transfers in tokens instead of gas, in one transaction](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/865)
- [Paying a transaction fee with an ERC20 token](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11818/paying-a-transaction-fee-with-an-erc20-token)

---

> Is it like on BTC that the miner itself just adds (one) transaction with a specific amount of a specific Token?

The protocol adds the mining reward (i.e. block reward, transaction fees, uncle fees) to the balance of the miner's coinbase address.

Comment: Just to make sure, there is no way that mining a block will reward the miner something else then ETH except the transaction fees which 'might' be Tokens? I just ask because i feel uncertain because of the 'standard' as if there are exception possible.

Comment: btw. i've changed the title accordingly to your note.

Comment: There are no exceptions possible for the block reward: on the main public  chain block rewards are in ETH only.