# Possible to use gas from the balance of a contract?

Tags: contract-design, contract-invocation, gas

When calling an external contract function from within a contract, does the gas come from the originating transaction?  If so, is there a way to use gas from the contract's balance?

example call:

```
someReturnValue = someContract.somePayableFunction.value(10).gas(10000)({someParam: "some value"});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current implementation sender always pays for gas. It's not possible to draw gas from another source such as a contract balance. There is discussion of allowing a contract to pay for gas but it's at the EIP discussion stage. I found a more details answer that might help over here: [Can contracts pay the gas instead of the message sender?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144/can-contracts-pay-the-gas-instead-of-the-message-sender)

Hope it helps.