# Can a contract's receive function use part of the value as additional gas?

Tags: contract-development, gas, receive

Since a contract's [`receive()`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#receive-ether-function) can only rely on 2300 gas being available, is there any way to use part of the `msg.value` to top up the gas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a security feature that gas cannot be changed within a contract. At first I thought maybe the refund mechanisms of `selfdestruct` and `SSTORE[x]=0` could have been used, but aside from them being under review for deletion ([EIP-3298](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3298)), the refund would only be [applied *after* the transaction](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3969/2256) to the benefit of the caller, not the smart contract itself. And finally, since the 2300 gas stipend itself is on the [wishlist for removal](https://hackmd.io/@vbuterin/evm_feature_removing#The-2300-gas-stipend) any way to circumvent this would be futile in the long run anyway...

Comment: See also https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/16498/2256