# When a contract transfers ether to an address, who pays the gas?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, gas

When a contract transfers ether to an address, who pays the gas?

For example:

```
function withdrawRefund(){
    uint refund = refunds[msg.sender];
    refunds[msg.sender] = 0;

    msg.sender.transfer(refund);
}
```

The sender pays the gas for the contract state change. 
But who pays the gas for the ether transfer, the sender or the contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the fees of a transaction (including the internal transactions it triggers) is paid by the transaction sender.

Comment: @aasafmo. Meaning, the gas is paid by the individual claiming the refund.

Comment: Thanks! So is there any scenario that the contract pays gas? because always the sender is not the contact.

Comment: @assafmo that is being discussed [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144/can-contracts-pay-the-gas-instead-of-the-message-sender). However, the answer is no, currently it's not possible.