# Pay for the users gas fee (ERC-721)

Tags: erc-721, payments

Is there a way for an NFT (ERC-721) so the contract creator pays for the gas fee when the user's trade tokens? Or add some sort of middleware CC payment so for the user that is not tech salvage not need to get ETH for my NFT to work?

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144/can-contracts-pay-the-gas-instead-of-the-message-sender.

Comment: @MaheshRajput thanks! Yes looks like that, but the ide with CC is still missing if possible?

Comment: Yes, the 0xcert project is designed for this use case. Check out their docs and their Gitter