# How dapp owners pay for their clients transcaction fees in the Ethereum Blockchain?

Tags: solidity, remix, dapp-development, blockchain-fork

I am currently dealing with a problem in Ethereum Blockchain. I wrote a smart contract in Solidity Language, about a site that someone can make his Registration and after the transaction is completed he should be able to login to his account making a call to the blockchain. If the blockchain accept the user details, he can have access to his account.

The problem is that i want, as a dapp owner, to pay for all the transaction fees to the Blockchain myself.

I found 2 possible ways to do that ([Can contracts pay the gas instead of the message sender?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144/can-contracts-pay-the-gas-instead-of-the-message-sender)), but as far as i know after the new Ethereum Upgrade, it was supposed to be included, meaning that the dapp owners could pay the fees to the Blockchain directly from their smart contracts by depositing funds in the contract.

So I am wondering, has anyone else heard anything about such a feature being added to Ethereum lately? If not, does anyone know if it is planned to be included in the near future?

Comment: You can use [Meta transactions](https://medium.com/@austin_48503/ethereum-meta-transactions-90ccf0859e84)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.