# Contract pays for gas

Tags: solidity, gas

Is there anything solidity in line that would let a contract with ETH assigned to, to pay gas.

Say I want something simple.

```
contract whatever {
uint256 one;
uint256 two;

function execute() public {
one = one + two;
//execute contract side
}
}
```

Does something like that exist? I checked the solidity docs, couldn't find anything to my knowledge.

Comment: No (and it's probably one of the most common questions on this website).

Comment: It's really not and you can check for yourself.

Comment: I must have seen in here it like 20 times before (one of them was actually yesterday if I remember correctly).

Comment: You could set the contract to send back some ETH after a successful TX but you will never be able to perfectly match the gas 1:1

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144/can-contracts-pay-the-gas-instead-of-the-message-sender

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way to have "gasless" txs go through contract side is through the implementation of OpenGSN - https://docs.opengsn.org/

Some of their examples are totally broken and I will update the answer with more relevant information on how to easily do it in a code snippet.