# Any updates on how to have 3rd party pay gas fees in dapps?

Tags: contract-development, gas, dapps

I've seen this old thread: [Can contracts pay the gas instead of the message sender?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144/can-contracts-pay-the-gas-instead-of-the-message-sender)

but most answers are 3-4 years old so I'm wondering if there are any newer/better methods that have come up since then? In my case I want to have a user of my dApp be able to make state changes to the smart contract without having to pay fees himself, but rather having the fees paid by some 3rd party, for example some common fund or something like that.

Maybe someone has some tipps on the current best practice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use meta transactions. Users sign the transaction what you want and you take the signature from them. Then, you have the data and signature. So, you can send those to a contract and parse from it.

For more info, you can google 'Ethereum meta transactions'