# Handling user transaction fee

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, smart-contract-wallets

Im creating a user whitelisting contract when a user asks for whitelisting hes paying for the contract execution how do i make it so that the creator of the contract pays for the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

you can refund gas with smart-contract but the user has to holds some ether and it's dangerous because hackers can repeatedly call the contract to deplete funds.
you can read [HERE](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144/can-contracts-pay-the-gas-instead-of-the-message-sender) for more details.